# Erlang Pattern-Matching boolean example

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I want to learn Erlang and in the book I have the exercise: 
 Write a module boolean.erl that takes logical expressions and Boolean values (represented
as the atoms true and false) and returns their Boolean result. The functions
you write should include b_not/1, b_and/2, b_or/2, and b_nand/2. You should not use
the logical constructs and, or, and not, but instead use pattern matching to achieve your
goal.
Test your module from the shell. Some examples of calling the exported functions in
your module include:

```
bool:b_not(false) ⇒ true
bool:b_and(false, true) ⇒ false
bool:b_and(bool:b_not(bool:b_and(true, false)), true) ⇒ true.
```

So the best solution I came up with so far is:

```
-module(b).

-export([b_not/1,b_and/2,b_or/2]).


b_not(false) -> false /= true.
%%%
b_and(false, false) -> false;
b_and(X, Y) -> X == Y.    
%%%
b_or(true, true) -> true;
b_or(X, Y) -> X /= Y.
```

How to solve the last example, I really don`t get it. Any help? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree a little with what @hdima said. The goal of this exercise **is** to practise pattern matching and not use any operators. The best way with pattern matching is to write down every case. So for `b_or` what are the different possible cases for the arguments? There are 4: `true`, `true`; `true`, `false`; `false`, `true`; and `false`, `false`. So just write down each case as a separate clause returning the correct value:

```
b_or(true, true) -> true;
b_or(true, false) -> true;
b_or(false, true) -> true;
b_or(false, false) -> false.
```

So looking at this answer you could be thinking well as many cases are the same why not optimise this to:

```
b_or(false, false) -> false;
b_or(_, _) -> true.
```

`_` is the *don't care* variable which matches anything and never gets bound. Well, both version behave the same if called with boolean values **BUT** they behave differently if called with non-boolean values. In this case the second returns `true` while the first one generates an exception. Usually it is better to generate an exception on bad input rather than let it pass and return a misleading answer, so the first alternative is a better solution.

Writing `b_and` (and `b_xor`) is left to you.

Sorry if this was a bit long but pattern matching can take some getting used to. The concept of writing down what you expect and not how to test for it is different from what is common in OO and imperative languages. (I give courses and this is a common hurdle)

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful and clear. Using "_" was a great tip as well.

Comment: This is actually exactly the same as my idea but I didn't want to spoil the solution completely. And now it's just a copy/paste exercise. ;)

Comment: @hdima Ah, but there is still `b_and` and `b_xor` left to do. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you limited only to pattern matching `b_not/1` should looks like this:

```
b_not(false) -> true;
b_not(true) -> false.
```

Try to use this idea for the other functions.

*Hint: for the other functions you don't need to write clauses for every possible case.*